# OpenGl crashes when adding vertices

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, vertex-buffer

Whenever I add vertices to my vertex array, my application crashes.

Here is the code:

```
const GLKVector3 Vertices[] = {


//8,9,0
LASH_BOTTOM_LEFT,
LASH_BOTTOM_RIGHT,
RECT_BOTTOM_L,


//9,1,0
LASH_BOTTOM_RIGHT,
RECT_BOTTOM_R,
RECT_BOTTOM_L,


//2,6,7
RECT_TOP_R,
LASH_TOP_RIGHT,
LASH_TOP_LEFT,

//3,2,7
RECT_TOP_L,
RECT_TOP_R,
LASH_TOP_LEFT,

//0,1,3
RECT_BOTTOM_L,
RECT_BOTTOM_R,
RECT_TOP_L,

//1,2,3
RECT_BOTTOM_R,
RECT_TOP_R,
RECT_TOP_L,

//2,5,3
RECT_TOP_R,
BACK_RIGHT,
RECT_TOP_L,

//3,5,4
RECT_TOP_L,
BACK_RIGHT,
BACK_LEFT,


//0,1,5
RECT_BOTTOM_L,
RECT_BOTTOM_R,
BACK_RIGHT,

//5,4,0
BACK_RIGHT,
BACK_LEFT,
RECT_BOTTOM_L,


};
```

**Setting it up:**

```
- (void)setupGL {


    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.myContext];

    self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
    self.layer.contentsScale = 2.0;

    // Create default framebuffer object.
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &defaultFrameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFrameBuffer);


    ViewToMap *view = [[ViewToMap alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 80)];
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
    view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.02;

    GLfloat coordToPixScale = 1.0;//[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;


    /*********************
     MAPPING UIVIEW ONTO THE FACE
     ****************/

    self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = true;



    // make space for an RGBA image of the view
    GLubyte *pixelBuffer = (GLubyte *)malloc(
                                             4 *
                                             view.bounds.size.width * coordToPixScale *
                                             view.bounds.size.height * coordToPixScale);

    // create a suitable CoreGraphics context
    CGColorSpaceRef colourSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context =
    CGBitmapContextCreate(pixelBuffer,
                          view.bounds.size.width*coordToPixScale, view.bounds.size.height*coordToPixScale,
                          8, 4*view.bounds.size.width *coordToPixScale,
                          colourSpace,
                          kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colourSpace);

    // draw the view to the buffer
    [view.layer renderInContext:context];

    // upload to OpenGL
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,
                 GL_RGBA,
                 view.bounds.size.width * coordToPixScale, view.bounds.size.height * coordToPixScale, 0,
                 GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelBuffer);

    BOOL repeatX = NO;
    BOOL repeatY = NO;

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, repeatX ? GL_REPEAT
                    : GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, repeatY ? GL_REPEAT
                    : GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);



    glGenBuffers(1, &texArray);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texArray);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(TexCoords), TexCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,0);

    /**************************
     ******************************************/

    // clean up
    CGContextRelease(context);
    free(pixelBuffer);

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, view.bounds.size.width * coordToPixScale, view.bounds.size.height * coordToPixScale);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexArray);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArray);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);



    self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(45.0f,0.9f, 0.01f, 1.0f);

    rotMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix,0,0,-2);
    self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix =          GLKMatrix4Translate(self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix, 0, 0, 1.2);


}
```

If I add 1 more vertex, everything seems OK but if I add another one it crashes (with no regards as to how their coordinates are and I think the vertex coordinates are perfectly OK).

What I get is a bad access error.

Draw call:

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {


    self.opaque = NO;

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    [self.effect prepareToDraw];

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sizeof(Vertices));
}
```

Comment: What happens if you put the call to glBufferData *before* the corresponding glVertexAttribPointer call?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No it does not change anything.

Comment: Better to put the code in the question.

Comment: Well I thought that maybe the buffer cannot store any more vertices or so, so I assumed this was a basic issue. The question you claim to be a duplicate I elaborated to a much greater detail because I was sure that there was more to it.

Comment: @MartinE.: The problem is, that in the code over at the other question, it doesn't show, how you're adding vertices. So its difficult to make a good answer.

Comment: aah I see. I am really sorry about that. I'll make sure to add it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have a hunch about this, but involves the driver being buggy (I can explain a crash, i.e. sudden program termination) in your case only with a buggy driver.

That adding a vertex *position* breaks your code is no surprise though. A vertex is the whole tuple of position, texture coordinates and the other attributes. So when you add positions, you also must add the other attributes. If you were using client side vertex arrays, this would explain the crash, but VBOs should catch this.

Anyway, you have those calls (annotated them).

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buf_size_t = sizeof(TexCoords), TexCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, attrib_elements_t = 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,0);
```

and

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buf_size_p = sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, attrib_elements_p = 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

You must make sure that

```
buf_size_t / (attrib_elements_t * sizeof(GLfloat)) 

    ==

buf_size_p / (attrib_elements_p * sizeof(GLfloat))
```

if this equality is not met, things will break in some form.

#### Update due to question edit

And finally the cause of the root of the problem:

```
 glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sizeof(Vertices));
                               ^^^^^^
                                     \--- This
```

glDrawArrays expects the number of vertices to draw (and not the size of the vertex array buffer).

The `sizeof` operator doesn't tell you the number of vertices in the array, but its size in units of `char`. You have to replace this with `sizeof(Vertices) / ( sizeof(GLfloat) * attrib_elements_p )`, `attrib_elements_p = 3` in your case.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the vertices have to have corresponding texture coordinates, right ? I always make sure to add them simultaneously but it still crashes...

Comment: @MartinE: Please understand that a vertex is not the position. A vertex is position + texture coordinate + normal + whatever other attributes you use. A vertex may even be no position at all, but some other variable, which is turned into a position by the vertex shader. Anyway, yes, you always must supply the whole set (or specify attibute binding divisors). However that is crashes is strange. Well, I'd have to see the whole program to make sense of it.

Comment: well this is pretty much the whole program. I did not change anything at all I just added a vertex to my vertices array and added the corresponding texture coordinates. I always did it the same way and the rest of the code always stayed the same.

Comment: @MartinE.: I don't see a drawing call (glDraw…)

Comment: @MartinE.: See my answer update. You were making a wrong draw call all the time. That it worked with a smaller number of vertices is, because memory is allocated in blocks and your wrong vertex number simply didn't exceed the limits of the allocation blocks of the vertex arrays. The added vertices made it overshoot.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked, but I did not quite grasp what the problem was, to be perfectly honest with you.

Comment: @MartinE.: glDrawArrays expects the number of vertices to render. But `sizeof(Vertices)` returns the size of the array has in memory in `char`s. A single GLfloat has a size of 4 chars (or even larger on some systems). And each vertex position has 3 elements, so the `sizeof(Vertices)` returns 3*4 = 12 times the number that's actually expected.